# installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

How to install Ubuntu on vmware.
How much ram should I give (if I have 6gb ram) and I have celeron processor

Comment: Vanilla Ubuntu (unity desktop) is normally slower in virtual machines, why not give a try to Xubuntu or Lubuntu(less demanding)

Comment: Do you need the steps to install ?

Comment: Your subject and question text is misleading a bit. Are you asking for virtualbox or vmware? those are 2 different softwares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule of thumb is 'not more than half' of the RAM for the virtual machine. It works for me with 2 GB RAM, but with 6 GB in the computer, you can increase it to 2,5 GB or 3 GB.

Comment: As a sidenote - you can change trhe amount of RAM for the virtual machine later on - so it's not a real problem to finetune later on depending on your needs.